# Assign same height to row of x images according to viewport height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a webpage in html and css with a "blog" header section.
I want the blog to contain a responsive grid of x images with the same height (width acc. to nat. dimensions) and the same padding displayed in y rows according to viewport width. Before splitting into multiple rows, I thought it would be best to start out by creating one long row of all the images. 
My question is - how to assign the same height (and corresp. widths) to all images in the row according to viewport height?
The height should be decided in pixels as a fixed percentage of the viewport height (3 min.-widths: 480px, 768px, 1140px).

This is what I came up with:

HTML

```
<ul class="blogGrid">
    <li>
        <img class="blogPost" src="//dummyimage.com/400x300/000/fff&text=hello+world" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="blogPost" src="//dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=hello+world" />
    </li>
...
</ul>
```

script.js

```
/** Helper function to extract common image height in pixels as a fixed percentage 
 *of viewport height according to media screen
 */
var imageHeight = function getImageHeight(h) {
    var h = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;

    if (h >= 1140) {
        imageHeight = 0.26 * h;
    } else if (h >= 768) {
        imageHeight = 0.32 * h;
    } else (h >= 480) {
        imageHeight = 0.34 * h;
    }

    return imageHeight;
};

/** Helper function to extract local image widths in pixels according to each image's natural       
 * dimensions
 */
var imageWidth = function getImageWidth(imageHeight, naturalWidth, naturalHeight) {
    return (naturalWidth / naturalHeight) * imageHeight;
};

/** Assigns height and width to each image
 */
var blogPostImg = document.getElementsByClassName('blogPost');

if (blogPostImg && blogPostImg.style) {
    blogPostImg.style.height = imageHeight;
    blogPostImg.style.width = imageWidth;
}
```

css

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
ul.blogGrid {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.blogGrid li {
    display: table-cell;
}
.blogGrid li img {
    display: block;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

But it doesn't work and now I am just stuck.
I have looked into some javascript lately, but i admit that i don't really know what i am doing at this point. I really don't want to offend anyone asking for advice in this kind of complicated case when clearly i am a rookie, but i do not know where else to ask and i really want to learn.

ALL COMMENTS TO MY ATTEMPTED CODE, HINTS, CODE EXAMPLES, INTEREST, ANYTHING..! IS MUCH APPRECIATED. THANK YOU

Comment: _"The height should be decided in pixels as a fixed percentage of the viewport height"_ What percentage ? Appear to be overwriting `imageHeight` function by setting `imageHeight` to a number value within the function ?

Comment: I'm guessing you have a VB background - based on your `imageHeight` function returning an undeclared `imageHeight` value! Also, you've declared a couple of functions, but you never actually execute them. I recommend you read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: Having said the above - you can do what you want with pure CSS

Comment: thanks a lot for the replies. @Jaromanda X: image width acc to nat. dimensions means that each image has a different width. With the same padding to all the images and same length rows, this means that some images will be "cut" at the rows' right margin. I then want the rest of that image to be displayed as the first "image" on the next row, and so forth. Is that still possible in pure css within a responsive design? And if yes, could you give some clues to how you would do that? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using jQuery to manipulate your DOM properties?

You could assign classes to your images and 'grab' them using a jQuery selector:
`$('.class-name')`. You'll then iterate through the collection that returns to set the properties on each one. That's one thing that could be tripping you up:

`var blogPostImg = document.getElementsByClassName('blogPost');`

is actually going to set `blogPostImg` to an array of elements. You're going to have to set something that iterates through it, like a forEach loop, to set the property on each one.

Another solution could be to wrap all the images in div rows, set the height based on the vh, and then use `overflow: hidden;` to clip the content. That wouldn't scale the image, though - just crop it.

A jsfiddle would be really helpful to see exactly HOW the code you wrote isn't working.